# show legends on top as like bottom appearance in c3js

Tags: legend, c3.js

I am using `c3.js` for implementing dashboard. It works pretty fine. But I just want legend on top as appeared at bottom. I want to draw chart as this sequence.

1. Legends
2. Chart
3. Ticks

This is sample figure what is want.
[image]
By searching in web, if I set legend configuration like this

```
legend: {
           show: true,
           position: 'inset',
           inset: {
                    anchor: 'top-right',
                    x: 50,
                    y: 0,
                    step: 1
                  }
        }
```

Then legend overlaps main graph as image below:

[image]
This is very typical requirement but not available in `c3js`. How can I do that?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the padding option to set a top gap:
http://c3js.org/reference.html#padding-top

And then set a negative y offset on the inset:

```
       legend: {
            position: 'inset',
           inset: {
                anchor: 'top-right',
                x: 50,
                y: -30,
                step: 1
            }
        },
       padding: {
            top: 30
        }
```